# Recursion - nth element from last in a linkedlist

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

Can someone please explain the following function ?

```
void printNthFromLast(struct node* head, int n) 
{
    static int i = 0;
    if(head == NULL)
       return;
    printNthFromLast(head->next, n);
    if(++i == n)
       printf("%d", head->data);
}
```

I just want to know how order of execution of statements occur in recursion i.e given recursive call is before the second if condition , so will the second if condition be checked ?

Comment: Interesting implementation.  It only has a hope of working once.

Comment: @Michael Burr - I agree. It will only work once.

Comment: Unless stack overflow occurs first ;-)

Comment: Of course the second if condition will be called (assuming no bugs in the code). At some point in the recursion one of the recursive calls will hit the terminating `head == NULL` condition. At that point the execution will return to the caller (one up in the recursion call stack) and thus the second if will execute. And so on and so forth up the recursive call chain.

Comment: An ugly useless trick.  Better try and implement the 2 finger method.

Comment: To make @AlanAu’s proviso explicit: it will work (first time only) if (A) the stack is large enough for as many nested calls as there are elements in the list, (B) the list-structure itself does not enter a loop, where a node links back to an earlier node and (C) all `next`-links point to valid nodes. I’m not so sure about “ugly”; it has a certain conceptual charm which is just spoilt by its not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to know how order of execution of statements occur in recursion i.e given recursive call is before the second if condition , so will the second if condition be checked ?

Yes, the second `if` condition will be checked, after the recursive call returns.  And it will return, provided the recursion terminates by reaching the end of the linked list.  This concept is essential to understanding recursion.  Most particularly, you must understand that each function call, including recursive ones, executes in its own context, and upon return control resumes immediately after the call.  It's associated with the flow of execution, not with the function that is called -- you don't lose your place by calling a function recursively.

Answer (score 0):

The function `printNthFromLast` calls itself recursively for every node in the linked list.  Upon return, `i` is incremented and the field `data` is printed only for the `n`th return from recursion, hence for the `n`th item from the end of the list, the last counting as `1`.  `printNthFromEnd` would be a more precise name for it.

This function is interesting as a quiz only: it updates a global inaccessible state and thus only works correctly once! It is the epitome of *non-reentrant* behaviour: not only should it not be used in different threads, it should not be used more than once, period. This method could be extended to fetch the nth mode from the end via another `static` variable:

```
void getNthFromEnd(struct node *head, int n) {
    static int i = 0;
    static struct node *np = NULL;
    if (head != NULL) {
        getNthFromEnd(head->next, n);
        if (++i == n) np = head;
    }
    return np;
}
```

A much better alternative is this:

```
struct node *getNthFromEnd(struct node *head, int n) {
    struct node *np;

    for (np = head; n > 0; n--) {
        if (np == NULL) return NULL;
        np = np->next;
    }
    while (np != NULL) {
        head = head->next;
        np = np->next;
   }
    return head;
}
```